# iOS Auto Layout Constraints - View Resize per 3.5 vs 4 inch screen

Tags: ios, iphone, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

I have been searching this, and I just cant seem to get it figured out.

How do I have a view resize based on the screen size of the phone, using Auto Layout constraints? I have a view that works perfectly for iphone 5, but I would like to shrink it for iphone 4.  What constraint do I use?

Thanks for any help or resources directed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just detect the device using UUID and set the constraint constant using that. If you are using storyboards, you would hook up the constraint to your code using @IBOutlet. The constraint you would want to adjust would have to move the object as you intend. For example, if you have a button and it has a constraint with its superview at to the bottom of the screen, adjusting the constant would move it vertically up/down depending on whether the constant is positive or negative.

Comment: I think this the best solution, a nice balance between auto layout and programatically adjusting the sizes. Although I am still working on my understanding of auto layout (frustrating), I appreciate your input!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not that easy. It depends on what do you have in your screen. I am not a big fan of using resolve with auto-layout, i like to take care of all my constraints. For example, if you have a button on the top right corner of your screen, i would use the Pin, and set up a constraint between your right side of the button and the side of the view, and the top side of the button and the top side of the view.

It is going to depend on how do you want then the distances between buttons, between buttons and view, collectionviewcells, labels, images, tableviews etc...

You can always go for the easy solution and cross your fingers. In storyboard, look for the Resolve auto layout issues button, click it and then press Add Missing Constraints. Cross your fingers and maybe that works for you! (If you don't find the button, make it easier: Editor->Resolve Auto-Layout Issues-> Add missing constraints)

Answer (score 0):

Apple has excellent documentation regarding the usage of constraints and Auto Layouts.

You can follow the guide here - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

or

Watch the wonderful WWDC Videos

- Introduction to Auto Layout for iOS and OS X
  https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202
- Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout
  https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=228

Comment: Apple is introducing new changes in auto-layout with iOS8. I would strongly recommend him to watch 2014 wwdc videos also. 2012 might be a little bit older.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/

Comment: If Apple's docs were that good we could eliminate the iOS section from stack :)

Comment: Dead link, consider replace it

Answer (score 0):

to shrink your view for a smaller screen, you will need to set constraints with the top layout guide and the bottom layout guide ( you do that by ctrl-draggin from the object to the top of the view or bottom of the view)

What i recommend is to put is to insert a view in your main view and "constrain" it with : 
- Top space to Top layout guide
- leading space to container
- trailing space to container
- bottom space to bottom layout guide

add all your elements inside this view but keep in mind to have some "flexible" space in the middle

```
----------------------------------
|           |                    |
|           |                    |
|---------Element----------------|
|                |               |
|                |               |
|--------------Element-----------|
|           |                    |
|           |                    |
|---------Element----------------|
|                                |
|                                |
|         Flexible space         |
|          no constraints        |
|                                |
|---------Element----------------|
|            |                   |
|---------Element----------------|
|            |                   |
|--------------------------------|
```